# Не знаю как определить стандартное название приложения "Камера"

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, microsoft-speech-sdk

В Windows 10 например калькулятор значится как приложение "calc" или "calc.exe", а как обозночается "Камера?"Просто "camera" не подходит.

Смысл приложения это голосовой помощник...Я его прошу открыть калькулятор он открывает, а прошу камеру выдает ошибку.Нужно стандартное название.Помогите пж!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте это:

```
Process.Start("microsoft.windows.camera:");
```

[*Источник*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37299685/run-camera-app-of-windows-10-from-desktop-application)

Comment: @ДанилБайрамгалеев, тогда отметьте этот ответ как правильный.

Answer (score 0):

Стандартное ПО по типу калькулятор(calc) или командная строка(cmd) и пр. находятся по адресу C:\Windows\System32. Проверьте расположение камеры, и установлено ли оно вообще.